# Calendar with Resource: change calendar view to show resources

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I have created an Group Work site on my SharePoint 2013 environment.  I've created a calendar with resources for employees to book.  So when you do a new entry in the calendar, you select the resources you want to book during that time frame.
Once booked, it shows the Title and time of bookings in the calendar view.  But I want to show the resources booked in the calendar view.

In other words if a user booked the *Conference Room and Company Laptop* for *Wednesday, 22 Aug* from *10:00 to 12:00* with the *Title: Demo*, I want to see in the calendar view on Wednesday "Conference Room, Company Laptop. 10:00 - 12:00"  Currently it says 10:00 - 12:00 Demo.  I want to replace 'Demo' with 'Conference Room; Company Laptop'

How can I change the Calendar view?  I did try to edit the Calendar view, but it does not give me the Resources field to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the calendar and select “Resources” column for the Week View Title and Day View Title, then it will display "Resources" on the view.

[image]

Another method, you can use JavaScript to customize Calendar view.

Customize calendar view in SharePoint:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/7a30e07b-6704-4579-88a1-c67f21ab5ab7/forum-faq-calendar-customization-in-sharepoint?forum=sharepointgeneral